# matrix multiplication, pandas bug or is the behavior just different than what I expect?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Setup

```
t = np.linspace(0,1,20)
T = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([t, t**2]), columns=['t','t^2'])

B = pd.DataFrame(np.row_stack((b1,b2) for b1 in np.linspace(-1.5,1.5) for b2 in np.linspace(-1.5,1.5)), columns=['b1','b2'])
```

What I want to do

```
T @ B.T
```

What works but seems to mean the other should work too....

```
T @ B.to_numpy().T
```

Since the dimensions are fine, it seems like it should work. The only thing that would make me believe it shouldn't work is that the indices aren't labeled the same way but it Pandas should assume I just want to to matrix multiplication, no?

These all work...

```
B.T @ B
T.T @ T

B @ B.T
T @ T.T
```

So to me it seems like a bug but I wanted to get a second opinion.

Comment: matrix multiplication in pandas does require common index/columns. I do find that reasonable.

Comment: I guess that makes sense because if you sort your dataframe it won't change the matrix multiplication if it figures it out only off of index?